# Creating an XML document through SQL, but I get syntax error

Tags: sql, xml, oracle, syntax-error

I have a small query to make an XML document:

```
Select XMLELEMENT(NAME movie,
XMLFOREST(Movie.name as title, year as year, rating as rating, plot_outline as plot, 
XMLELEMENT(NAME actor, 'actor',
XMLAGG(
XMLELEMENT(NAME role, Acts.role )
),
XMLAGG(
XMLELEMENT(NAME person, Person.name))   
)))
as result from Movie, Acts, Person
where Movie.mid = Acts.mid
and Acts.pid = Person.pid
```

But I get this error:

```
ERROR:  unnamed XML element value must be a column reference
LINE 3:    XMLELEMENT(NAME actor, 'actor',
           ^
```

This was supposed to be my expected result in XML:

```
<movie>
<title>Godfather, The</title>
<year>1972</year>
<rating>9.0</rating>
<plot>A Mafia boss' son, previously uninvolved in the business, takes over when his father is critically wounded in a mob hit.</plot>
<actor>
<role>Don Vito Corleone</role>
<person>Robert De Niro</person>
</actor>
<actor>
<role>Someone else</role>
<person>Someone else</person>
</actor>

</movie>
```

How do I get rid of this error message?

Answer (score 1):

1) You can omit "name" word in xmlelement. xmlelment(name "name"... ) =   xmlelment("name"...).

2) unnamed XML element value must be a column reference - that error is raise by xmlforest function.

`xmlforest( col1, col2 as "TEST") - works fine`

`xmlforest(col1,xmlelement("TEST")) - throws error should be xmlforest(col1,xmlelement("TEST") as "xxx" )`

3) `XMLELEMENT(NAME actor, 'actor'` you don need this. If i understand your query. You try to concatenate two xmlagg into one xmlelement. To do this  use `xmlconcat(xmlagg(..),xmlagg(..))`

4) Finall query.

```
   select xmlelement(
             movie
           , xmlforest(Movie.name as title
                     , year as year
                     , rating as rating
                     , plot_outline as plot
                     , xmlconcat(xmlagg(xmlelement(role, Acts.role)), xmlagg(xmlelement(person, Person.name))) as "actor"))
             as result
      from Movie, Acts, Person
     where Movie.mid = Acts.mid and Acts.pid = Person.pid
```

You also have to add proper group by clause to it. Because it raise another exception. ORA-00937: not a single-group group function